# JavaScript scrollIntoView

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

I have question about how scrollIntoView is working, so why scrollIntoView working like this:

```
liItems.forEach(val => {
   val.addEventListener('click', e => {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   document.querySelector(val.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
     ...
   })
 })
})
```

But not working like this:

```
liItems.forEach(val => {
   val.addEventListener('click', e => {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   val.getAttribute('href').scrollIntoView({
    ...
   })
 })
})
```

Comment: `getAttribute` returns a string (or null). Strings don't have a method called `scrollIntoView`.

Answer (score 2):

[`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) is a method on [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)s.

`querySelector` returns an `Element`.
That's why the first example works:

```js
const elem = document.querySelector(val.getAttribute('href')); // this is an Element
elem.scrollIntoView(); // OK!
```

[`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute), however, is a method on `Element` which returns a `string`:

```js
const someHref = val.getAttribute('href'); // this is a string
someHref.scrollIntoView(); // error :( strings don't have scrollIntoView
```